# How to add tooltip in Word using Word Javascript API?

Tags: ms-word, office-js

I want to add a tooltip on hover on selected keywords in the Word document using Word Javascript API from the add-in. Something similar to the picture shown below:

[image]

This feature is available in Word using hyperlink and inserting ScreenTip. Is it possible to do the same using the add-in API? If it is not possible directly, is there a workaround/hack to emulate the same feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unfortunately not currently supported in the Word JS API. Please make sure to add this request to our user voice channel! 
https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/category/163566-add-in-word

thanks!

Comment: there is no workaround for this. maybe inserting a comment?

Comment: yes, finally resorted to inserting comment. struggling with deleting the comments now, have started another question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44804345/how-to-delete-an-inserted-ooxml-comment-using-word-js-api